# Jquery code works on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code and works on firefox ut in chrome do nothing. The version of jquery is  jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.4

chrome version 54.0.2840.99 m
firefox version 49.0.2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function transferirAIvr(){

    //deshabilita boton transferencia
    var textoBtn = $("#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul").text();
    alert(textoBtn);

    $("#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul").text("");
  alert("1");
    $("#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul").text("Transfiriendo...");
    alert("2");
    $('#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul').prop("disabled", true);
  alert("3");
  $('#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul').attr("disabled", false).delay( 3000 );
    $("#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul").text(textoBtn);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btonTrasnferenciaStateFul"onclick="transferirAIvr()" type="button">Transferir</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[here the link](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FA95BD7LF9KH)

Comment: What should the code do, as in what is the expected behavior and what are you getting

Comment: Did you accidentally check the *"Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs"* box in the alert box at one point? It works just fine for me.

Comment: change text button and then original text button back... I put alert to see the changes, but nothing happens on chrome

Comment: FYI, the `.delay(3000)` will have no effect.

Comment: If you're wondering why the button doesn't update between the alerts on Chrome but does on Firefox, it's just a matter of when the browser decides to redraw the page. But you're not going to be using alerts like that anyway, so maybe you need to take a step back and ask about the original problem.

Comment: Yes I think the browser not redraw the button, but i dont know why... if I quit the alerts anyway nothing happens ... if on you browser works, maybe my browser have something wrong

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout instead of delay.

```
function transferirAIvr(){

    //deshabilita boton transferencia
    var textoBtn = $("#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul").text();

    $("#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul").html("");
    $("#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul").html("Transfiriendo...");
    $('#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul').prop("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul').attr("disabled", false);
        $("#btonTrasnferenciaStateFul").html(textoBtn);
    }, 3000);
}
```